# winforms panel hide and show

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have two panels occupying the same space in one side of a splitviewcontainer.
I want to dynamically show or hide one panel or the other.

Approaches I've tried so far are:

```
if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.Contains("cat")) {
    menuItemPanel.SendToBack();
    foreach (Control control in menuItemPanel.Controls)
        control.SendToBack();
    menuItemPanel.Visible = false;
    categoryPanel.Hide();

    categoryPanel.Visible = true;
    categoryPanel.BringToFront();
    foreach (Control control in categoryPanel.Controls)
        control.BringToFront();
    categoryPanel.Show();

    // ...
}
```

and the converse for the else case.
None of these seem to work. That is the categoryPanel is shown when a category node is selected, but the screen shows blank space when a menuItem node is selected.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code doesn't make much sense, re-ordering the controls in the panels is not what you want to do.  Also sounds that the code in the else clause is failing, code you didn't post.  Do it like this instead (a guess):

```
bool categorySelected = treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.Contains("cat");
menuItemPanel.Visible = !categorySelected;
categoryPanel.Visible = categorySelected;
```

Comment: This code works for me.  Double check in the designer file that both of your panels are in the same split container, and that one panel is not inside another panel.

Comment: Good point, that's going to happen when you drop the second panel with the designer.  Use View + (Other Windows) + Document Outline and drag the second panel out of the first panel.

Comment: I tried something similar already, before I posted the code, I simply had if(...contains("cat")){menuItemPanel.Visible = false; categoryPanel.Visible = true;} else { ... /* Let me check if this code never gets called as you say, will get back shortly. */ }

Comment: Thanks, Moozhe & Hans. I dragged the panels out of each other. How do I get them both docked in the splitviewcontainer? Do I have to set this in code (not a big deal) or is there a way to do it in the designer?

Comment: Use the same Document Outline window to select the panel, then set its Dock property.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I never new such a tool existed.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Name.Contains("cat"))
    {
         menuItemPanel.Visible = false;  
         categoryPanel.Visible = true;   
    }
```